# Why is this fringe behavior happening when I am filtering a matrix of data with Butterworth filter using scipy's Python?

Tags: python, image-processing, signal-processing, highpass-filter, data-filtering

I am high-pass filtering a matrix of data using Python 3.7 with scipy 1.6 (using `signal.butter` and `signal.cheby2`). When I plot the filtered data using `imshow()`, an undesired fringe behavior occurs on the left edge of the data (input data on the left, filtered data on the right):

[image: On the left side, the original data; on the right side, the filtered data]

Such fringe behavior becomes more visible as filter order increases and it is a problem for the signal processing pipeline because the filtered data is then binarized (filtered data on the left, binarized filtered data on the right):

[image: On the left side, the filtered data; on the right side, the binarized filtered data]

The main issue is that in the binarized data, I get true signal mixed with the fringes from the filtering.

My doubts are: why is this behavior hapenning and is it possible to suppress it? how?

Additional details:

Code

```
sos = butter(order, wCutoff, 'hp', fs=defines.FS, output='sos')
filtered = sosfilt(sos, data)
```

[Bode plot of the filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxfHL.png)

Comment: This is an edge effect. Maybe padding the image on the left side in a way that avoids the big jump on that edge will avoid this effect? You'd crop the padding off after filtering.

Comment: *also* consider asking this on the stack exchange for DSP https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi @CrisLuengo! I checked the padding by using the sosfiltfilt function - it by default  adds padding to the signal. By using it, no fringe behavior happens. However, when I configured the sosfiltfilt function with padtype=None and padlen=0, no fringing happens, even if I use an order 20 filter. I read the documentation of the sosfiltfilt function and it says it applies a forward-backward filtering method wich causes a zero-phase delay and a filter order twice the original. The issue is solved but I do not understand how and why the phase is causing such undesired fringes.

Comment: Thanks @ChristophRackwitz for considering my question and for your suggestion.